# Where are you flying vs flying to

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can someone help me understand the correct grammar please?

Where are you flying or where are you flying to?

Answer (score 2):

They are both grammatically correct and in almost all situations, they mean the exact same thing, particularly if you are speaking to an airline passenger.  They both mean, "What is the destination of your flight?"  In extremely formal writing you might want to leave off the "to" because some people object to prepositions at the end of the sentence, but must people accept this in modern speech or even writing.

If you are speaking to a pilot (or navigator), it is possible that "Where are you flying?" could be asking for the flight route, especially in a situation like recreational flying where the flight begins and ends in the same place.  In that case, the two questions are different:

> Q1: Where are you flying?
>
> A1: I'll head out over the ocean, turn south along the shore for about twenty miles, and then head back inland to my starting point.
>
> Q2: Where are you flying to?
>
> A2: Nowhere. I'm taking off and landing from the same airport.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "where are you flying to" is correct

Possible answers:

> Q: Where are you flying? 
>  A: In the sky? 
> **vs**
> Q: Where are you flying to? 
>  A: New York!

Hope this helps!